# WPF: Why SharedSizeScope is not working as expected?

Tags: wpf, xaml, sharedsizegroup

I'm trying to create a datagrid-like view with merged cell. Everything is OK except I cannot `ShareSizeScope` between the header row and the rest row.
You can see in the screenshot below, the columns is not aligned except the first one.Would anyone kindly point out what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.
[image]

My XAML:

```
<Grid  Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35" MaxHeight="35" MinHeight="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="35"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_A" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_B" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_C" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_D" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_E" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-1" Grid.Column="0"></Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-1" Grid.Column="1"></Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-1" Grid.Column="2"></Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-1" Grid.Column="3"></Border>

        <TextBlock Text="Col 1" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Col 2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Col 3" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Col 4" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Col 5" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="4"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestReportData.Items}" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource noStyleToListboxItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CaseName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" ></Border>
                    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelList}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_B" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_C" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_D" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_E" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="0"></Border>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="1"></Border>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="2"></Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChannelName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalTestTimes}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FailedTestTimes}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="2"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FailedTestRate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="3"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why are you using a ListBox to do that? You should use a ListView or a DataGrid instead, these controls natively support multiple columns.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I've updated the screenshot. I don't use a ListBox because I want to merge some cells of the first column

Comment: You didn't set `IsSharedSizeScope="True"` anywhere in your code, so the SharedSizeGroup has no effect. You should set IsSharedSizeScope on a common ancestor of the headers and rows

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks for your quick reply. I'm sorry that I did not notice that my code is not shown completely because my markdown issue. Corrected it. You can see now, I did set IsSharedSizeScope="True"

Comment: This requires some trial and error. so i don't want to post an answer with out trying it out. 
your usage is seems o'k. I would try splitting the first grid into 2 columns 
and move the content of <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_A" />
outside having the first child grid and the listbox items comprise only of B,C,D,E 
Iike you did in the listboxitem    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col_A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768161/wpf-why-sharedsizescope-is-not-working-as-expected/53278863#comment51468106_31768161) by [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) you should set the `IsSharedSizeScope` property to `True` on ancestor of all grids where `SharedSizeGroup` is suppozed to work

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The OP's code already shows that it has `IsSharedSizeScope` set to `True`.