# How to use a Grid inside a WPF ItemControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've a WPF page where I need to display things in a form of a grid.

I've a number row that are dynamic and I will have different template depending on the type of object.

I've tried to put my headers in grid with `SharedSIzeGroup` specified, and then having each of my item in an individual grid with the same SharedSizeGroup name.

It doesn't seems to work, my header and each values are not shared at all :(

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Title1" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Title2"  FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Title3"  FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Title4"  FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="4" Text="Title5"  FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LoggingRule.MachineStateLogging}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/> 
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Grid.Column="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Is this something possible?

Comment: Assuming that you just want a collection of items displayed in columns with headers, why not use a `DataGrid` control?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: Why SharedSizeScope is not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768161/wpf-why-sharedsizescope-is-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @Peregrine I thing the DataGrid cannot have different template per row? Also, I really need no lines displayed, no selected line, no scrollbar, no clickable column(just a header).